# Trouble requesting scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

Good morning, not sure if this is the right place to ask but we had several issues reported to us with the oAuth window constantly flashing up when using our install screens.  We have debugged this down to the attempt to get a number of scopes, and narrow it down to the scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

The response from the https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest is not returning the scope we requested.

This was working previously but seems to be causing problems now.  Do you know has anything changed that could be impacted this or if there is any easy way to fix?
This is my call to get scope and request permission:

```
  'apiKey': '---------',
    'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
    'clientId': '--------.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': SCOPE
}).then(function () {

    GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    GoogleAuth.signOut();

// Listen for sign-in state changes.
    GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

    // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)

    var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
    setSigninStatus();

});
```

Later in the process we check has the user now got the request scope:

```
var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE);
```

If not we recheck in case there was a delay in getting the permissions.

Sorry if I haven't supplied all the information and if you need more please let know.

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell me what is SCOPE.  and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this isnt enough to test it.

Comment: var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile ';
SCOPE += 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly ';
SCOPE += 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login ';
SCOPE += 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly';

Comment: I am unable to show you this issue happening or set up a full set of the code due to the API keys etc

Comment: Just grabbed the network response after the call:

"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read openid email profile"

Doesnt seem to have the scope we are expecting.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue since today. Users are unable to sign in because of this. I will try to post more details later.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at your scopes

```
googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly 
googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly 
googleapis.com/auth/drive 
googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read 
googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read
```

I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem but its probably not helping 
i think you should consult the scope page [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

```
googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly 
googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly 
googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Drive gives you access to `View and manage the files in your Google Drive` which means the two read only ones are pointless.

These two are also the same

```
googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
```

and its the same as

```
googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

You can use the [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to test that you have access to the things you need.  Rather than just including a lot of extra scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a change on Google's end.

When you request `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` you now actually receive the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` scope.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open [Google OAauth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)
2. Request the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope and exchange your code for access token.
3. Get your access token and open this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?alt=json&access_token={your_token}
4. You now receive the following scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`
5. If you check against `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` your app is now broken.

This seems to have happened recently (in the last 24 hours), so it could be a defect on Google's end or some undocumented change.

We've added a work-around in our app by doing an additional check for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`

Hope this helps.

Comment: very frustrating we have it on our webapp side of things but also included in our extension so would need to deploy about 3 solutions.  Any idea why google changed and are they likely to roll back

Comment: I have no idea really. There's no mention about this change in any official document yet. Luckily for us we only needed to make changes in our application servers, so it was an instant fix for all users.

Comment: Was trying to find a change log or road map as we have a change ready just needs tested. Don't want to release incase the roll it back.  Hard to get a support contact or page